# How to fix a corrupt 3gp File

Tags: video, 3gp

My phone ran out of space when recording a video.  I have the 3gp file, but cannot open it.  Any hints on how to open it an convert it into a working file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`ffmpeg`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and see if it can copy the file to another container - maybe only the container is broken. 3GP should be easy to convert to MP4.

```
ffmpeg -i input.3gp -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: It gives a "header not found" error :

Comment: FFmpeg version SVN-r10635, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  libavutil version: 49.5.0
  libavcodec version: 51.44.0
  libavformat version: 51.14.0
  built on Oct  1 2007 15:21:19, gcc: 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-8)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xb7f5dda0]mov: header not found !!! (err:0, moov:0, mdat:0) pos:36
simon.3gp: Error while opening file

Comment: Hm. Can you try with `-er 4` to enable error concealment?

Comment: Oh, and you have tried VLC, have you?

Comment: Yes I have tried VLC.  And the `-er 4` option results in "Output file does not contain any stream"

Comment: @Lloyd Meh, if it can't even find the appropriate headers your file will proabably be too damaged.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the options though.

Comment: Journeyman - why did you revert my edit?

Comment: @Hashim It's fine, I reverted it to yours. Perhaps adding a description of *why* you changed it would have helped. Sometimes there are reservations w.r.t. “technical” edits, which AFAICT are more frequent on Stack Overflow.